# General formula for $\sin(A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_n)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I was wondering if there could be a general formula for this. Somehow, I managed to get (after some very small experimentation, so I'm not sure of what I'm going to say) that

\begin{align}
\sin(A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_n) & =\cos A_1 \cos A_2 \cdots \cos A_n \times \\  & \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \tan A_i - \sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n} \left(\tan A_i \tan A_j \tan A_k\right)\right) \\
\end{align}

And I cannot prove it.
Can anyone help me prove or disprove it?

Comment: Not sure, but induction on $n$ might be the way to go?

Comment: @Shuri2060 Maybe. I tried using induction but then I was encountering $\cos(A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_n)$ whose formula I'm not sure of, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true for $n=5$: 
$$(\text{left side}) - (\text{right side}) = \sin(A_1)\sin(A_2)\sin(A_3)\sin(A_4)\sin(A_5) $$

I suspect that on the right side, for each $k$ with $2k+1 \le n$ you need 
$$(-1)^k \sum_{1 \le i_1 < \ldots < i_{2k+1}} \tan(A_{i_1}) \ldots \tan(A_{i_{2k+1}})$$